# How to get the row index so I can color cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, colors, indexing

I have a grid view which contains some sequence numbers. Each column needs to have unique number sequence. It is editable and if the user input number which is already in this particular column the cells are colored in red.

So far I color only the second cell of the 2 wrong cells (with same values). How can I color both cells. As far as I know I need to use the row index as well but I have no idea how..

Here is the code

```
            //colum2
            string sValue2 = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;

            if (Values2.Contains(sValue2))
            {
                // This value is a duplicate - color red
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                 //Response.Write("Warning... Error in pad no: " +e.Row.Cells[2].Text+ " dupliated value: " +e.Row.Cells[3].Text);


            }
            else
            {
                Values2.Add(sValue2);
            }
```

and the same for all the 8 columns

Hopefully it's understandable.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Is this code taken from an event handler? What is the `e` variable?

Comment: Did you tried this?: `e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;`

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
This is the method signature and its arguments ;)

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy this is what I'm doing isn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get your question right, you would like to find out the RowIndex for the row which already contains the same data in the same cell, and change it's color to red.

You could write a method to change every cells color to red which contains that data.
Something like:

```
void colorCells(GridView GV, int CellIndex, string Text)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in GV.Rows)
    {
        if(row.Cells[CellIndex].Text == Text)
            row.Cells[CellIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        //might use else to set to default color
    }
}
```

And then you could use like this:

```
    //colum2
    string sValue2 = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;
        if (Values2.Contains(sValue2))
        {
            // This value is a duplicate - color red
            colorCells(/* Get the reference for the grid view, e.g.: gridView1*/, 4, sValue2); 
        }
        else
        {
            Values2.Add(sValue2);
        }
```

Comment: Wow that's great. Thank you. Now I tested it and the result is not what I expected but the code seems very correct to me
What I get is now the first cell with the wrong value colored not the second (but both has to be colored).
Only when I have a third value - then the two cells are colored red but respectively not the 3rd one. 
I don't get it :(

Answer (score 2):

Your question wasn't very clear but I'll try to help and respond from what I understood.

There are different ways to get the row-index.

It depends on which event of the GridView control, your code-logic needs to be executed:

- _RowDataBound: `e.Row.RowIndex`
- _RowCommand: `((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow.RowIndex`
- _RowEditing: `e.NewEditIndex`
- _RowUpdating, _RowDeleting and _RowCancelingEdit: `e.RowIndex`

Hope this helps.

Sample Code:

```
private bool IsCellToHighlight(GridViewCell cell)
{
bool highlightCell = false;
// Put your cell checking condition
// Example ..
highlightCell = (string.Compare(cell.Text, "Check Value", true) == 0);
return highlightCell;
}

private void HighlightCells(GridViewRow row)
{
for(int c=0; r<row.Cells.Count; c++)
{
if(this.IsCellToHighlight(row.Cells[c]))
{
// Apply required styling Code
// ..
}
}
}
```

Another way of doing this is using JQuery:

1. At first just load the grid as is
2. Then execute the same using JQuery on client-side

Check out these links:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=259

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article970-aspnet-gridview-jquery-tips-and-tricks-part-1.aspx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=250

---

Disclaimer: This is just one way of doing. Though a bit crude, you could build over it.

Comment: Yeah it is RowDataBound method. Sorry I forgot to mention that this code goes there. 
So the gridview is using this method and I know that there is this e.Row.RowIndex but do you know how can I use it in order to color both cells
As you can see so far I kind of hardcoded each column: 
 e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

I don't know how this is working exactly but it's coloring the second cell with wrong value. 
Can you understand it better now :)
Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe you could try something like this: Run a loop to read each column/cell and then check the value in each iteration. I've added the sample code in my above-answer.

Comment: If I get it right this will check each cell in the whole gridview right?
What I need is checking each columns and only duplicate cells in this particular column to be colored. 

P.S javaScript is not my strength :)

Comment: Then just reverse it. Bit I'd suggest not to do it in the _RowDataBound event.